# How can I loop through common fieldsets in a single form in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops

I have a form, which contains multiple virtual fieldsets.

Eg, MyForm:

```
Name1
Age1
Location1

Name2
Age2
Location2

Name3
Age3
Location3

Submit
```

If I allow the user to dynamically create more field sets on the client how can I loop through all fieldsets where name(x) is set and perform an similar action for each group, using the integer (1,2,3 etc) as a unique identifier?

I want to specify the actions once, loop through and each time change the variables used according to the number of the fieldset.

Right now, I am doing it manually for 3 hardcoded fireldsets, but it won't scale:

Pseudocode:

```
if($name1 is set) {
do something using $age1 and $location1
}
if($name2 is set) {
do something using $age2 and $location2
}
if($name3 is set) {
do something using $age3 and $location3
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
    $maxIndex = 3

    for(var $i=1; $i<=$maxIndex; $i++){
       $name = $_POST["Name$i"];
       $age = $_POST["Age$i"];
       $location = $_POST["Location$i"];
       //do something using $name, $age and $location
    }
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Can you use the $i in a variable name like that? In my tests it's not working.

Comment: D'oh - single quotes. This solution worked for me based on other considerations in how my JS was setup on client side.

Answer (score 3):

you can name your elements `name="name[1]"`, `name="name[2]"` and so on.

and in php do something like:

```
for($i=1;$i<=count($name);$i++){
// do the stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrays for your input fields. Then you can create any number of the following blocks:

```
<input name="name[]" />
<input name="age[]" />
<input name="location[]" />
```

In PHP you can loop through these parameters:

```
foreach($_POST['name'] as $key => $value) {
    $name = $_POST['name'][$key];
    $age = $_POST['age'][$key];
    $location = $_POST['location'][$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array in php for making

In first from of fome you can use

```
<?php
//n is no of records u want at one time
$available = $n;

for($i=1; $i<=$available; $i++){
 ?>

 Name <input type=hidden name="pname<?=$i?>" value=<?=$pid?>>

 Age<input type=text name="age<?=$i?>" />
 Location<input type=text name="age<?=$i?>" />
 <?php


 }
 ?>
```

in action form you can use to save these multiple recordes at one time

```
 <?php
$available_count = $n;

for($i=1; $i<=$available_count; $i++){
        $pname = "pname".$i;
        $age = "age".$i; 
        $location = "location".$i; 


        $pname1 = trim($_POST[$pname]);
        $age1 = trim($_POST[$pname]);
        $location1 = trim($_POST[$location]);
  //now you can insert these values into table/views

  }
  ?>
```

Hope you will find better help...